# "add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int"

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am learning how to code a game in python(version 3.6), and I have come across an error that has me lost. I  tried to run my code and this error message that traced back to sprite.py(A file that I imported from python's library). This is the error message popped up:

> File "C:\Users\aveil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142,
> in add self.add(*group) TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int >>>

This is the code that the traceback lead to:

```
 has = self.__g.__contains__
    for group in groups:
        if hasattr(group, '_spritegroup'):
            if not has(group):
                group.add_internal(self)
                self.add_internal(group)
        else:
            self.add(*group)
```

I did not paste the whole sprite.py file because it has 1.6k lines, but I hope this is enough context. I did not write sprite.py, and am still relatively new to coding, so this error has me stumped. I am not sure where the "int" is or how to change it from an integer to an "iterable".
I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: It might be more helpful if you posted the code you DID write, as opposed to the code you didn't write.

Comment: The error is that `group` is an integer, while `*group` is used to unpack a sequence into positional arguments for the method call. We don't know your data or what `self.add` is, so its hard to suggest a solution. You are right that posting huge amounts of code is unfeasable. But it would help to know what `self.add` accepts for parameters. If its reasonable to pass a single integer, then `self.add(group)` may be the right this. But this is complicated code trying to do different things with different input and its hard to guess what the author intended.

Comment: You show a loop over `groups`, which the code seems to expect will contain either objects with `_spritegroup` attributes, or iterables. You are somehow giving it a value that is an integer. Show the full traceback, including your code that passes in `groups` to this code, and maybe how you set it up.

Comment: My 2 cents: Think of `foo(*[1,2,3])` equivalent of `foo(1,2,3)`. This is what `*` is doing *in this context*. The code you showed lead to something like `self.add(*1)`, well, `1` cannot be expanded like a list can, so you got this error. Being iterable is just a fancy name for an object that can be iterated `for x in <iterable here>` is the canonical example of iteration. IHIH

Comment: We don't need to troubleshoot the `add` method, the error message makes it clear what's going wrong with the call to it. The question is, why is your code giving this library code an integer when it expects something else. Show *your code* that is calling this code!

Answer (score 1):

*args --> when passed as an argument to a function causes the iterables (list, tuples) to be unpacked and passed to the function.

**kwarg --> when passed as an argument to a function causes causes unpacking of dictionary

(Please note that args and kwargs are representative valiables, they can be any name)

In you case self.add(*group) , group is not iterable but a int value. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your code, not the PyGame Sprite library.

When a sprite is created, it is possible to *optionally* send some `SpriteGroup` groups that the sprite should be a member of.  These are put into the **parent** `__init__()` call:

```
class Block( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, png_image, x, y ):
       # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self, some_groups )    # <-- HERE
       self.image = png_image
       self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
```

However, somehow your code has an integer (number) value instead of a SpriteGroup, and the sprite class is complaining about that.

I'm just guessing, but I suspect you have something like:

```
class Block( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, png_image, x, y ):
       # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self, x, y )    # <-- HERE
       ...
```

Because this gives the error you quoted.  To fix it just remove all arguments from that `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__` call, except the `self`.

Comment: Sorry ,@Kingsley, for not getting back for so long, but I tested your suggestions, and I only got more errors. I believe that most of the integers that I added in sprite constructor functions are needed, as to make the sprites run properly.

Comment: @Simone - yes, keep them in the sprite constructor, but *not* the call to the **parent** `Sprite.__init__()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Kingsley, and to everyone who suggested solutions. My code is running properly now.

Comment: The error was fixed by editing the placement of the update function and making sure that everything was placed in it properly.